# SQL Select items by percentage and timeago

Tags: mysql, sql

That was my SQL Select without the 90% Filterung under 30 Minutes.

```
SELECT id, name, price, pricebefore, link, imagelink, updated, site, siteid FROM items 
WHERE (case when pricebefore3 is NULL then pricebefore else pricebefore3*1.5 end) >= pricebefore 
AND price < pricebefore 
AND isbn != -1 
AND (100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 80 
ORDER BY updated DESC 
LIMIT 25 
OFFSET 0
```

It works good, but i have  the problem that items over 90% must be 30 Minutes old.

```
SELECT id, name, price, pricebefore, link, imagelink, updated, site, siteid FROM items 
WHERE (case when pricebefore3 is NULL then pricebefore else pricebefore3*1.5 end) >= pricebefore 
AND price < pricebefore 
AND isbn != -1 
AND (100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 80 
AND ((100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 90 AND updated < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
ORDER BY updated DESC 
LIMIT 25 
OFFSET 0
```

So i tried this one. But that gives me only items over 90%...

I need all items (also over 90%) but if there is an item OVER 90% it must be 30 minutes old. Under 90% it can be also 1 sec old... but over 90% i only need items over 30 minutes old.

So result gives me all items, but if there are items over 90% i just want items who are older than 30 minutes (just for the 90%+)

Comment: Share a sample dataset and the expected result.

Comment: I Just need the WHERE clause ((100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 90 AND updated < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) combined with that two statements...

Answer (score 0):

You need OR as follows:

```
.....
.....
( ((100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 80  and (100-(price/pricebefore)*100) < 90)
 OR
((100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 90 AND updated < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) )
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace these conditions:

```
AND (100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 80 
AND ((100-(price/pricebefore)*100) > 90 AND updated < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

with this `CASE` expression:

```
AND 1 = CASE
  WHEN (100-price/pricebefore*100) > 90 THEN updated < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
  ELSE (100-price/pricebefore*100) > 80
END
```